# Как сделать обновление двух строк Postgres?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Необходимо сделать обновление 2-х строк одной таблице Postgres. Написал такой запрос:

```
UPDATE tasks
SET npp = 
    CASE taskid
        WHEN 271939 THEN 1
        WHEN 271940 THEN 2
    END
WHERE taskid IN (271939, 271940);
```

Запрос выполняется, но не срабатывает. Пишет, что `Affected rows: 2`. Но ничего не обновилось по факту. В чем проблема и как решить задачу?

З.Ы. Значения `271939, 271940, 1, 2` берутся из скрипта и не могут не существовать.

Comment: Отчего-то мне кажется, что update вы выполняете в транзакции, которую затем не коммитите.

Comment: @Мелкий В программе `navicat` делаю `new query`, чтобы проверить запрос перед реализацией в скрипте.

Comment: не знаю таких. Через `psql` запрос корректно выполнен и данные обновлены.

Comment: @Мелкий только что выполнил там и ничего не произошло.

Comment: что значит фраза "ничего не произошло"?

Comment: @Мелкий `Update` выполнился, но данные не изменились. Более того, делаю просто `update tasks set npp = 1 where taskid = 271936` и тоже ничего. Update проходит, затронута строка, но данные не обновились...

Comment: Вам же уже сказали магическое слово `COMMIT`...

Comment: @Akina я не делаю никаких транзакций. Я напрямую выполняю команду.

Comment: *я не делаю никаких транзакций* Попробуйте всё же - голый коммит ошибки не даёт. *Я напрямую выполняю команду.* Напрямую - это в консольном клиенте?

Comment: Вопрос решен. Оказалась какие-то ограничения на поле, чтобы не было повторяющихся значений... Странная архитектура тут выдалась, но решено путем **добавления** транзакций с заменой значений в 3 шага.